# Extending abstract class with Generics in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

While extending the class `TextClass`, which accepts `T`, I want the type of the property `eventList` in the class `ImplTestClass` to be an array with all the possible values of `AllowedEvents`

I can not seem to figure this one out. If someone can point me in the right direction I'd be very happy!

```js
type EventMap = Record<string, unknown>; 

abstract class TestClass<T extends EventMap> {
  public eventList: Array<T[keyof T]>;

  constructor() {
    this.eventList = [];
  }
}


interface AllowedEvents extends EventMap {
  created: { time: string; userId: number; createdId: number; },
  removed: { time: string; userId: number; removedId: number; }
}

class ImplTestClass extends TestClass<AllowedEvents> {
  getEventList() {
    return this.eventList;
    // I would like `eventList` to have the type 
    // ({ time: string; userId: number; createdId: number; } | { time: string; userId: number; removedId: number; })[]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using a type alias instead of an interface¹ and not explicitly specifying it extends `EventMap`:

```typescript
type AllowedEvents = {
    created: { time: string; userId: number; createdId: number };
    removed: { time: string; userId: number; removedId: number };
};
```

That type is a valid subtype of `Record<string, unknown>`, so you can use it as the type argument for the abstract base class. When you use it as the type argument, your subclass code sees the type you want for `eventList`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAsgQzFAvFAShAYwHsAnAEwB4BnYEgS0QHMAaKAV0QGtEiB3RAHwBuAFAi0AIxok0BYFAIAbNFSpQAKhBoBhZaorqoEAB7AkZNfCSoMAqAG8RUZ1DBsJiugSMJkAGToaAC4oAEESGRADAG1OCBAiADMNAF1hMRcFIkRpNjlSAAoASgcnTJdgAAtAgDoIX2AAmmwoaJTRTIBfEW6RUEgwxUU+CDIrZDUcR0yCEgg0MzIQ+yhgOgBbCBDpBkYhdioIEgBJJahENnWJI-3Z+cXTkIuro6hOjpc59aIEM5W1zbbWi7fZsQ4nM7Pa4kfZfH6jR7nS7Qt6id5iJQqNTHdZgRSaHR6NQmMyICwaLTAXRYiihIYjMYNKh2aYuRgQYDjRqBYDFUrlT4ctgkRCrapUOoNJrAD4CgD0coF5QAegB+MrObqdIA)

---

¹ FWIW: I don't know *why* it has to be a type alias rather than an interface. When I [tried it as an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAsgQzFAvFAShAYwHsAnAEwB4BnYEgS0QHMAaKAV0QGtEiB3RAHwBuAFAi0AIxok0BYFAIAbNFSpQAKhBoBhZaorqoEAB7AkZNfCSoMAqAG8RUZ1DBsJiugSMJkAGToaAC4oAEESGRADAG1OCBAiADMNAF1hMRcFIkRpNjlSAAoASgcnTJdgAAtAgDoIX2AAmmwoaJTRTIBfEW6RBjMSRNloUMVFPggyK2Q1R0yCEgg0MzIQ+yhgOgBbCBDpBkYhdioIEgBJVahENi2JU6OFpZWLkOvb06hOjpdFraIES7rTY7Pa0A5HNgnc6XN53EhHX7-SYvK43OGfUS9JQqNRnLZgRSaHR6NQmMyICwaLTAXQ4iijca8SbTYBUOxzFyMCDAFlNYDFUrlH7ctgkRAbapUOoNPnfIUAenlQvKAD0APxlZzdTpAA), TypeScript didn't let me use it as the type argument on the base class, saying it lacked the index signature.